# Editing the computed field function code

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck

My friend gave me a drupal website to maintain. It was initially built and maintained by some other guy he knew. Now he wants to change some things.

The changes are in content type field -- computed and it is not showing any computed code text area. Just "This field is COMPUTED using computed_field_field_total_charges_compute()."

I don't want to disrupt or break the system and would definitely like to view and make my changes to the previous code instead of not know what the previous guy wrote.

Where can I find/view the computed code function. It must be being saved in DB or somewhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

The function must be in template.php of the current theme enabled. You can check enabled & default theme under admin/appearance. There must be some preprocess_form_field_name() hook implemented for the computed field.